# Update message on web page after form submit without using flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a simple form with the Rails scaffold that contains a list of checkboxes. After the user clicks the "submit" button, it accesses the database and retrieves a number of objects pertaining to the values selected by the check boxes, and returns the result as a string.

I'd like to display this string on the web page after the operation completes, but until now the only option I saw was to use flash[:notice], which worked successfully but was susceptible to CookieOverflow exceptions.

I was wondering if anyone could help me discover a simple method for achieving this result while avoiding CookieOverflows with longer strings. It's an extremely simple form without any frills, so the simpler the implementation, the better, as it's only going to be used by me and a select few people.

Assume that `message_string` is ready to be posted to the page; this is the code snippet I was using to do so. `index.html.erb` is the only page being used, so I'm having it redirect to itself to avoid any "Template missing" errors when calling the controller action that creates the string.

```
respond_to { | format | format.html { redirect_to '/index', notice: message_string } }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You do realize that the reason cookies are used is that you want the flash to persist across requests, don't you?

Comment: Of course, but if the message I want to display is bigger than 4K, the page will raise a CookieOverflow exception, which I *don't* want. :)

Comment: Your other option is to store the message in session and display it from there. Unfortunately, if you are using CookieStore, you are out of luck there too. You can probably add functionality to split the message in a number of parts and store each part in a different cookie.

Comment: Yeah, that suffers from the same size restrictions as using flash. However, I'm looking into using ActiveRecord to store session info, will update if this pays off.

Comment: Rails has support for DbStore and that used to be the default in Rails 2. It has very poor scalability. Even if scalability is not a concern, you get a performance hit. Are you sure you want to show your users a 2000 character message?

Comment: If the data being returned from the database is 2000 characters, yes. The form isn't for the everyday user; it's for a group of people who work with the data in the database and will be used for debugging purposes.

Comment: In that case, you should consider submitting the form using AJAX and getting back a JSON reply. Your success handler can then display the message before redirecting the user.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like all roads lead to AJAX. I'm going to need to look into how to achieve this...if you have any hints I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to replace the content of a `<div>`.

Comment: I was considering this, but I'm pretty new to AJAX and javascript so I wasn't quite sure how to tackle this...could you give me a point in the right direction, please?

Comment: This Railscast [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery?view=asciicast) covers AJAX well.